# Is ther any tool to extract keywords from a English Text or Article In Java?

Tags: java, parsing, text, semantics

**I am trying to identify the type of the web site(In English) by machine.** I try to download the homepage of the web iste, download html page, parsing and get the content of the web page. Such as here are some context from CNN.com. I try to get the keywords of the web page, mapping with my database. If the keywords include like news, breaking news. The web site will go to the news web sites. If there exist some words like healthy, medical, it will be the medical web site.

There exist some tools can do the text segmentation, but it is not easy to find a tool do the semantic, such as **online shopping**,  it is  a keywords, should not spilt two words. The combination will be helpful information. But "oneline", "shopping" will be less useful as it may exist online travel...

• Newark, JFK airports reopen
• 1 runway reopens at LaGuardia Airport
• Over 4,155 flights were cancelled Monday
• FULL STORY

```
* LaGuardia Airport snowplows busy Video
* Are you stranded? | Airport delays
* Safety tips for winter weather
* Frosty fun Video | Small dog, deep snow
```

Latest news

```
* Easter eggs used to smuggle cocaine
* Salmonella forces cilantro, parsley recall
* Obama's surprising verdict on Vick
* Blue Note baritone Bernie Wilson dead
* Busch aide to 911: She's not waking up
* Girl, 15, last seen working at store in '90
* Teena Marie's death shocks fans
* Terror network 'dismantled' in Morocco
* Saudis: 'Militant' had al Qaeda ties
* Ticker: Gov. blasts Obama 'birthers'
* Game show goof is 800K mistakeVideo
* Chopper saves calf on frozen pondVideo
* Pickpocketing becomes hands-freeVideo
* Chilean miners going to Disney World
* Who's the most intriguing of 2010?
* Natalie Portman is pregnant, engaged
* 'Convert all gifts from aunt'  CNNMoney
* Who controls the thermostat at home?
* This Just In: CNN's news blog
```

Comment: So, you try to get keywords from the text or you already have DB with keywords and want to find them in the text to determine text's topic?

Comment: I try to get the keywords for the web site. After that, I use these words to do mapping , i can identify the type of the web site. 
In the database, there exist some words such as:
Website for News: news, breaking news, 
website for shopping: ebay, amazone....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand, that in general you need a tool for **semantic classification of text information**. In this case mapping texts to keywords from database is not the best way, since it doesn't take into account *polysemy* and *synonymy* of words. To overcome these restrictions many techniques were invented. The most well-known is **[LSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latent_semantic_indexing)** and its descendants like **[PLSA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_latent_semantic_analysis)** or **[RI](https://web.archive.org/web/20170424034018/http://www.sics.se/~mange/papers/RI_intro.pdf)**.

But none of them will solve problem with terms of several words by itself. The most strict way to treat such terms is to **concatenate words in terms**. That is, replace all occurrences of "online shopping" by single concatenated term "onlineshopping". Yep, it will take O(N * M), where N is a number of words in text and M is a number of multiword terms to be processed, but my own experience shows that this is the most robust and computationally efficient way (please, notify me if you know better way).

If you already have stream of stemmed tokens, you can also use some kind of **pattern matching** to find sequences of words, composing term.

**Also FYI**: in the field of natural language processing there are methods, which can help to get keywords and concepts from the text itself. See [AlchemyAPI - archived](https://web.archive.org/web/20160313075813/http://www.alchemyapi.com/) for example.

Answer (score 0):

I try to get the keywords for the web site. After that, I use these words to do mapping , i can identify the type of the web site. 
In the database, there exist some words such as:
Website for News: news, breaking news, 
website for shopping: ebay, amazone....